# Does the GraphAPI support SSO (auto-login) for Domain Users?

Tags: node.js, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I have a web app (node.js) which will access the GraphAPI through OAuth using ADAL to my company's Azure AD. Does it support SSO such that the domain user doesn't need to give credential again after domain login?

Answer (score 0):

The Azure AD Graph API is not used for SSO, you can refer to [its API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/azure/hh974476.aspx).

> The Azure Active Directory Graph API provides programmatic access to Azure Active Directory through REST API endpoints. Apps can use the Azure AD Graph API to perform create, read, update, and delete (CRUD) operations on directory data and directory objects, such as users, groups, and organizational contacts.

For more details of single sign-on, please see the doc [What is application access and single sign-on with Azure Active Directory?](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-appssoaccess-whatis/)